# Gridview Autoscroll to selected item in windows store app C# xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, datagridview, windows-store-apps

What i want is to scroll gridview to selected item .

i tried the following but doesn't work

```
 Tumbnailsgrid.SelectedIndex = Mainflipview.SelectedIndex;
 var scrollBar = Tumbnailsgrid.GetFirstDescendantOfType<ScrollViewer>();
 scrollBar.ChangeView((double)Tumbnailsgrid.SelectedIndex / tumbnailimagelist.Count,   scrollBar.VerticalOffset,1,true);
```

Answer (score 1):

finally worked with MakeVisible method code follows

```
 Tumbnailsgrid.SelectedIndex = Mainflipview.SelectedIndex;
 var zoomLoc = new SemanticZoomLocation() { Item = Tumbnailsgrid.SelectedItem };
 Tumbnailsgrid.MakeVisible(zoomLoc);
```

Comment: Here's my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841841/calculate-horizontal-offset-to-scroll-listview-to-the-center-of-the-selecteditem I tried your answer here, but when I flip many times the `FlipView`, and return to check my `ListView`, I see that it didn't scroll to the `selectedItem`! Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test but what about `Tumbnailsgrid.ScrollIntoView(Tumbnailsgrid.SelectedItem);` ?

Comment: i tried that but not working , nothing happens with that code

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
Tumbnailsgrid.UpdateLayout(); 
Tumbnailsgrid.ScrollIntoView(Tumbnailsgrid.SelectedItem);
```