# Calculate Horizontal Offset to scroll ListView to the center of the SelectedItem

Tags: c#, listview, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, scrollviewer

I am building a photo application, using a `FlipView` and a `listView` as a Pagination. 
When I click on the thumbnail picture in the `ListView` it shows me the same picture in the `FlipView`. And when I swipe into the `FlipView`, any photo selected will select the same picture in the `ListView`. This is done by adding to both of them:

To the `ListView`:

```
SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, ElementName=flipView1, Mode=TwoWay}
```

And to the `FlipView`:

```
SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, ElementName=listView1, Mode=TwoWay}
```

And to the `ListView SelectionChanged` event I added:

```
 if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
        listView1.ScrollIntoView(e.AddedItems.First(), ScrollIntoViewAlignment.Leading);
```

My only problem is that when I swipe the `FlipView`, the desired picture is selected in the `ListView` but the `ScrollViewer` is not scrolled to it. I tried using `WinRTXamlToolkit` to change the position of the `ScrollViewer`:

```
private void pageRoot_Loaded()
        {
            // count number of all items
            int itemCount = this.listView1.Items.Count;
            if (itemCount == 0)
                return;

            if (listView1.SelectedIndex >= itemCount)
                listView1.SelectedIndex = itemCount - 1;

            // calculate x-posision of selected item
            double listWidth = this.listView1.ActualWidth;
            double xPos = (listWidth / itemCount) * listView1.SelectedIndex;

            // scroll
            var scrollViewer2 = listView1.GetFirstDescendantOfType<ScrollViewer>();
            if (scrollViewer2 != null)
                scrollViewer2.ChangeView(xPos, 0.0, 1);
        }
```

The first time `listWidth` is `1600.0` and then it becomes `0.0` all the time, which gives `xPos = 0.0`!

How can I fix this?

Comment: a `ListViewItem` has a `BringIntoView` method

Comment: `BringIntoView` doesn't exist in Windows 8.1! `BringIntoViewOnFocusChanged` exists for the `ScrollViewer` but it doesn't work as expected!

Comment: Is your list vertical or horizontal scrolling?  I'll try to dbl check but bring into view I thought is on the listview1.  Are all your items the same size in the listview?

Comment: My `ListView` is horizontally scrolling, and yes all the items are the same size.

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx

You should use one of the two "ScrollIntoView" methods.

Comment: I've tried using:  
`listView1.UpdateLayout();
listView1.ScrollIntoView(listView1.SelectedItem);`


But it gives me the same bug: when I flip into the `FlipView` many images (without looking at the `ListView` after each flip), when I look at the `ListView` I find it didn't scroll to the `SelectedIndex`

Comment: I've also used:
`var zoomLoc = new SemanticZoomLocation() { Item = listView1.SelectedItem };
listView1.MakeVisible(zoomLoc);` and I'm getting the same bug...

Comment: Sounds difficult. From personal experience the method I mention has worked for me in the past.  try making a dead simple app that only has a vertical listview with items and then once items loaded use ScrollIntoView to go to the third item.  If that works your at least on a good path.  Then slowly add more to it like horizontal scrolling and see if it still works etc.

Comment: If you want to just hack it to work there is another way by scrolling to an X position like you mention, but it really isn't best practice for this situation from what I understand

Answer (score 0):

`ListView.ScrollIntoView()` should work. There might be issues with calling a method to scroll a `ScrollViewer` while it's already scrolling though. I would try fiddling with `ScrollViewer.InvalidateScrollInfo()` which might speed it up. Otherwise - you could try handling the `ViewChanging/ViewChanged` events to see if it's scrolling and try to use that information together with `ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs.IsIndeterminate` to chain the calls.

Also check my answer to this question:
[Centering selected item in a scroll viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595675/centering-selected-item-in-a-scroll-viewer)